# INSERT ALL INTO a table over a dblink .. Is it possible?

Tags: oracle, dblink

When I execute the following:

```
INSERT ALL INTO table@database_link(columnName) VALUES (columnValue)
SELECT columnValue FROM localTable;
```

I get an error

> SQL Error: ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote
>   database
>   02021. 00000 -  "DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to use a DDL operation on a remote database.
>              For example, "CREATE TABLE tablename@remotedbname ...".
>   *Action:   To alter the remote database structure, you must connect to the
>              remote database with the appropriate privileges.

Note that when I do a regular (not an insert ALL into) ... the insert works over the database link. (Grants are valid).

There are also NO triggers on either tables.

And I explicitly need the INSERT ALL INTO, to allow for the ability to insert into multiple tables.

Are INSERT ALL INTO operations not allowed into database link tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This message is a little misleading but anyway according to [the Oracle SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2095116)

> You cannot perform a multitable insert into a remote table.

Comment: Yep ... definitely misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> Are INSERT ALL INTO operations not allowed into database link tables?

Unfortunately not. Note the second item in this list:

> **Restrictions on Multitable Inserts**
>
> You can perform multitable inserts only on tables, not on views or
>   materialized views.
>
> You cannot perform a multitable insert into a remote table.
>
> You cannot specify a table collection expression when performing a
>   multitable insert.
>
> In a multitable insert, all of the insert_into_clauses cannot combine
>   to specify more than 999 target columns.
>
> Multitable inserts are not parallelized in a Real Application Clusters
>   environment, or if any target table is index organized, or if any
>   target table has a bitmap index defined on it.
>
> Plan stability is not supported for multitable insert statements.
>
> The subquery of the multitable insert statement cannot use a sequence.

Source: [Oracle 9i documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90125/statements_914.htm#2080119)